# Получение текста и ссылок на фото из поста wall.get

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Как получить текст и ссылки на фото с помощью wall.get
Точнее как вывести?
есть`<div id='news'>
 <div class='text'>Тут должен быть текст</div>
 <div class='photo'><img src="Полученная ссылка на фото"></img></div>
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

При выполнении [wall.get](https://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=wall.get) вы получите массив объектов - записей стены, у каждой записи есть свойство attachments, которое выглядит как массив объектов, например:

```
[ { type: 'photo',
    photo: 
     { pid: 324712924,
       aid: -7,
       owner_id: 1,
       src: 'http://cs7002.vk.me/c540101/v540101001/b426/pwZv_7VRUZs.jpg',
       src_big: 'http://cs7002.vk.me/c540101/v540101001/b427/d74pq3EOlDI.jpg',
       src_small: 'http://cs7002.vk.me/c540101/v540101001/b425/FX3qTGF6efg.jpg',
       src_xbig: 'http://cs7002.vk.me/c540101/v540101001/b428/aXdb2cLe2Eg.jpg',
       width: 609,
       height: 543,
       text: 'Россияне часто доказывают свой талант и становятся чемпионами в самых разных областях — от программирования до фигурного катания. Подобные талантливые люди — главное достояние России.',
       created: 1394495246,
       access_key: '7ff74f52272b5a4d7b' } }

]
```

Достаточно проверить тип на 'photo' и получить картинку нужного размера (src, src_big, src_small, src_xbig) GET-запросом по прямому URL

```
// $postAttachments - массив attachments записи на стене
foreach ($postAttachments as $attachment) {
     if ($attachment == 'photo') {
          echo "<div id='news'>
                 <div class='text'>{$attachment['text']}</div>
                 <div class='photo'><img src='{$attachment['src_big']}'></img></div>
                </div>";
     }
}
```